# Show that $\|.\|_{1/2}$ is not a norm.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, nonlinear-optimization, regularization

Show that $\|.\|_{1/2}$ is not a norm. would anybody guide me that how can i prove or disprove?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality. All you need is a counter-example to show it isn't a norm. For example in $\mathbb R^2$ consider $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: Or $(1,4)$ and $(4,1).$ In either this case or yours we have an instance of $\|a\|+\|b\|<\|a+b\|$.